# Dynamically Change the Text of RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button

I am creating a quiz application in android.For each question  I have set up 4 radio buttons for the user to click. How do i change the text of the radiobutton dynamically for each question? The text for these radio button are stored in a raw text file.

Comment: have u achieved your task i m doing the same but i have taken tablelayout and tablerow i m adding radiobuttons for everyrow in radiogroup and then adding whole tablerow in  tablelayout but its only adding last value selected in all options

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go.

> I have set up 4 radio buttons for the user to click.

You must have defined them in radioGroup,right?

Then you can iterate in RadioGroup to set names to RadioButton
or you can get RadioButton by index and set name to it.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group);

    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup .getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get an object of the button by using

```
RadioButton button = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
```

Then write:

```
button.setText("This is another text...");
```

Didn't try to run it, but it should work...