# Android - How to retrieve text from edit Text to radio button?

Tags: android, radio-group

Actually I am creating a trivia app. For creating questions, I need to assign the options to radio buttons in a radio group, which has to be done dynamically. For giving the options, i want to enter the option in an editText and grab it into radio group on clicking a button. This has to be done for every option which has to be placed in the radio group. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Change the Text of RadioButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013835/dynamically-change-the-text-of-radiobutton)

Comment: My assignment is regarding pulling the information from edit Text field and assigning it to radio buttons each item clicked on a button. I am told to do this way because we are creating questions and options for those in an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RadioButton` extends `Textview` basically, which means you can call [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText%28%29) and [setText (CharSequence text)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) on any object instance of  `RadioButton`

to get text from `EditText` is `EditText.getText().toString()` all these widget's **mother** is `TextView`

Helpful??

Comment: Yes. I already knew this. But this scenario was not applicable for the radio button text setting from edit text

Comment: what?? i dont get you, all i am saying is do this `RadioButton.setText(EditText.getText().toString());` and you are saying it is not applicable? how @VarunVarma

Answer (score 0):

Use edittext.addTextChangedListener() and onaftertextchange call    radioButton.setText(edittext.getText().toString());

Code

```
    uid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_UserId);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioInstall);
    uid.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            radioButton.setText(uid.getText().toString());
            if (radioButton.getText().equals("Install Now")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```