# How do I add an EditText to a RadioButton?

Tags: android, android-edittext, radio-button, android-relativelayout, radio-group

I want people to be able to change their status from inside the app with a dialog with radio buttons, so they can change from Online, to Away, Do Not Disturb, and Offline. I want people to be able to add a custom status with an EditText radio button.

This is what I have so far:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbOnline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/online"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbAway"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/away"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbDnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dnd"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbOffline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/offline"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbCustom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    
</RelativeLayout>
```

The last one, `rbCustom` is the radio button that should have an edittext. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: You can try showing `EditText` when that `RadioButton` is selected

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and got my solution from this. The answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11014041/10974012.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking if I could add an edittext to that radiobutton instead of the default text.