# RadioButton's Text not displaying after setTextSize call

Tags: java, android, xml, android-radiobutton

I have programmatically added several `RadioButton`s to a pre-existing `RadioGroup`. The buttons themselves are there and are clickable, but their texts just won't appear. I have set their texts using the `setText` method, and by using `Toast` and `RadioButton`'s `getText` method, I was able to confirm that all of the buttons do possess the texts they should have - they just don't display them.

I have made sure to set their alpha to 1, the text size to 20sp, their visibility to `View.Visible`, and I tried changing the text color and the background color several times to contrasting colors, but the text still didn't appear.

Can someone please help me figure out how to make the text appear?

---

The Java code:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < CERTAIN_CONSTANT_VALUE; i++)
        {
            RadioButton r = new RadioButton(this);
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            r.setLayoutParams(params);
            r.setId(View.generateViewId());
            r.setText(answers[i]);
            r.setOnClickListener(this::onBtnClicked);
            r.setTextSize(20, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
            r.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
            r.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            r.setAlpha(1);
            r.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            r.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            this.radioGroup.addView(r);
        }
```

The `RadioGroup` in the XML file:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
</RadioGroup>
```

---

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**

Java:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        String[] answers = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth"};
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            RadioButton r = new RadioButton(this);
            android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            r.setLayoutParams(params);
            r.setId(View.generateViewId());
            r.setText(answers[i]);
            r.setOnClickListener(this::onBtnClicked);
            r.setTextSize(20, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
            r.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
            r.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            r.setAlpha(1);
            r.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            r.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            radioGroup.addView(r);
        }
    }

    public void onBtnClicked(View view){}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure answers[i] has a value?  Does calling getText on it return the correct value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Change the Text of RadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013835/dynamically-change-the-text-of-radiobutton)

Comment: @GabeSechan I am sure answers[i] has a value, as "toasting" it displays the expected value.

Comment: @ShabbirHussain Sadly, it does not. I believe my case is different. I still tried iterating over the buttons like the answer in that post suggested, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?  This code should work.  Perhaps `CERTAIN_CONSTANT_VALUE` is incorrect?

Comment: @RyanM `CERTAIN_CONSTANT_VALUE` equals 4, and I tried running the loop without it (using explicit 4 instead). As for the minimal reproducible example - I've just added it.

Comment: Where? You haven't edited the question since it was posted.

Comment: @RyanM sorry for the delay in the edit, it kept telling me to reindent the code.

Comment: Maybe, maybe the answers[1] is returning null?? Or, try creating the radio group in XML not java, maybe it will work.

Comment: Wait a minute, you have set your radio button alpha as 1 which is fully opaque. Try setting it to 0 n check if it works.

Comment: @ElPrimo setting it to 0 didn't work, I think that 0 = fully opaque, not 1. As for answers[1] returning null - if you check my minimal, reproducible example, you'll notice that I assigned the array's values at declaration and that none of them are null.

Comment: No @Or Abulafia you are wrong. 1 = fully transparent and 0 = fully opaque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change setTextSize to this :

```
r.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20f);
```

Comment: This solves my problem. I seem to have put the parameters in the wrong order. Thank you for noticing.